# Show that two geodesics $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ can't meet in point $q\in S$ when $K\leq 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I have some problem in a part of proof. The question:

Let $S$ a orientable surface whit gaussian curvature $K\leq 0$. Then two geadosics $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ that goes from $x\in S$ can't meet each other in a point $y\in S$ such that the trace of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ form the boundary $\partial R$ os a simple region $R\subset S$.

Sketch of proof: It's proved by absurd. Suppose that the geodesics meet each other in $y$ and form the boundary of $R$. By Gauss-Bonnet, we have $$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{s_i}^{s_{i+1}} k_g(s)ds+\underset{R}{\int\int} Kd\alpha+\theta_1+\theta_2=2\pi 
$$
$\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are not tangent, so we have $\theta_1+\theta_2<2\pi$. And with $K\leq 0$ we conclude that $\underset{R}{\int\int} Kd\alpha+\theta_1+\theta_2<2\pi$, an absurd.

Here's my question: In the proof of Do Carmo's book, he used the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{s_i}^{s_{i+1}} k_g(s)ds=0$, and i can't se this intuitively or expressing this formaly.

I have this idea: we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{s_i}^{s_{i+1}} k_g(s)ds=\int_{\gamma_1}k_g(s)+\int_{\gamma_2}k_g(s)$, so if we consider the fact that they form a boundary of a region, we can consider $\gamma_1$ going $p\to q$ and $\gamma_2$ in the opposite way, $q\to p$, then they cancel each other. This is the unique idea until now, i'm stucked. To be honest, i don't like this argument and think is wrong.

Ps.: Sorry my english mistakes, if someone can correct i'll be grateful.

Comment: Hint: Geodesics have zero curvature.

Comment: Oh my! I forgot that! Thank you, it's so clear now.

Comment: One more thing, it's correct put $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{s_i}^{s_{i+1}} k_g(s)ds=\int_{\gamma_1}k_g(s)+\int_{\gamma_2}k_g(s)$ (even the two integrals equal zero, is just for curiosity).

Comment: Geodesics have zero *geodesic curvature*, but that's what $\kappa_g$ is. Yes, you have the sum of the two integrals. Actually, your cancellation argument doesn't work in general for non-geodesic segments.